# How to use DocuSign to implement the simplest electronic signature function?

Tags: docusignapi

Thank you for your reply, I now want to implement the simplest electronic signature.

Party A: Steve, the signing representative of our company

Party B: The dealer who signed the contract with us

We integrate docusign through our website. What should I do? Please give me the detailed steps.

create envelopes,
Generate signature view,
Jump to docusign signature, and I have handled the callback process.

I need best practices and I want to know the electronic signature process of our representative, Steve.

Comment: Do you want to write code to build an integration to do this? or you want to do this manually from web site?

Comment: I want to write code to build an integration to do this. And the code has been written, and I can complete the signing and callback of my own URL page. The integration code I wrote only needs to be signed by the customer. I want to know whether it is necessary for the company representative to sign. If signing by the company representative is necessary, how should I modify my code? There is no such thing in the API documentation.

Comment: That's because I explained in your other question, signing has to be done by a human. If you want the document to be signed by the company's rep, but you do not wish that rep to take any action, then you have to have that rep sign the document, take a picture of this document with the rep's signature and use that as the document that the customer has to sign. The rep's signature is already in it, the rep doesn't need to sign.

Comment: Thanks.I downloaded the SDK sample, which contains a World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf file. If I use the file in the sample, I can control the signature position through signHer, but if I replace it with my own file, I cannot use signHer to control the signature position and signature view. The singer needs to manually drag it from the left into the file. Where can I control the signature using my own file?

Comment: I've solved it, there is a hidden anchor on the example that I haven't been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the document(s) you wish to be signed.
2. Send them only to company rep to sign.
3. Get finished document with company's rep signature only and download this document as a PDF. This PDF will be the base document signed by any and every customer.
4. Create a template in DocuSign.
5. Upload document from #3 into this template.
6. Add a placeholder "Customer" signer recipient.
7. Set signing elements (tabs) for customer to sign in document from #3 that you uploaded in step #5.
8. Use code to generate envelope from template in step #4 to send it to any customer you want.